# How can I do a switched outer join with more than one table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following select

```
        Select Exam.Name, 
               Test.Type,
               Test.TestId, 
               Topic.Name, 
               Exam.Name
        FROM Test
        INNER JOIN Exam
           ON ( Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId)
        INNER JOIN Topic
           ON ( Test.TopicId = Topic.TopicId)
        WHERE Test.TestStatusId = 1
```

When Test.Type = 1 then there will be an Exam.Name for the test
When Test.Type = 2 then there will be a Topic.Name for the test

Is there a way I can do an outer join and just return Name based on if Type = 1 or 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a  `left join` and a `case`

```
Select Test.Type,
       Test.TestId, 
       case when Test.Type = 1 then Exam.Name
            when Test.Type = 2 then Topic.Name
       end as Name
FROM Test
LEFT JOIN Exam ON Test.ExamId = Exam.ExamId
LEFT JOIN Topic ON Test.TopicId = Topic.TopicId
WHERE Test.TestStatusId = 1
```